# Limit $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{4x+12}}{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{4x+12}}$

Tags: limits, radicals

Using the equivalency, I got the answer equal to $1$, however the answer is given as $\frac34$.

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Clim_%7B+x+%5Cto+%5Cinfty+%7D%5Cfrac%7B%5Csqrt%7Bx%2B1%7D%2B%5Csqrt%7Bx%2B2%7D-%5Csqrt%7B4x%2B12%7D%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7Bx%7D%2B%5Csqrt%7Bx%2B2%7D-%5Csqrt%7B4x%2B12%7D%7D) also gives $\frac34$.

Could someone tell me that the given answer is wrong or I made a mistake!

Comment: rationalize the denominator

Comment: do you know the taylor expansion of $\sqrt{1+1/x}$ around infinity? if yes, pull out a $\sqrt{x}$ and then use it repeaditly

Comment: Well I think binomial expansion may help.

Comment: Pleae improve the post by adding additional context. What is the source of the question? What method have your tried? If you were unable to use the standard methods, such as L'Hopital's rule, what problem did you encounter? Posts that merely state an unmotivated problem are discouraged on this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substitute $x=1/t$; then, with a simple massage, the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}
  \frac{\sqrt{1+t}+\sqrt{1+2t}-2\sqrt{1+3t}}
       {\sqrt{1+2t}+1-2\sqrt{1+3t}}
=\lim_{t\to0^+}
  \frac{(1+\frac{1}{2}t)+(1+t)-2(1+\frac{3}{2}t)+o(t)}
       {(1+t)+1-2(1+\frac{3}{2}t)+o(t)}=
\frac{-3/2}{-2}=\frac{3}{4}
$$
using the first order Taylor expansion.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$\sqrt{4x+12}=2\sqrt{x+3}$$

Now set $1/x=h\implies h\to0^+$

$\sqrt{x+a}-\sqrt{x+b}$
$=\dfrac{\sqrt{1+ah}-\sqrt{1+bh}}{\sqrt h}$
$=\dfrac{1+ah-(1+bh)}{\sqrt h(\sqrt{1+ah}+\sqrt{1+bh})}$

$$\implies\dfrac{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x+3}}{\sqrt x-\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x+3}}=\dfrac{\dfrac{1-3}{\sqrt{1+h}+\sqrt{1+3h}}+\dfrac{2-3}{\sqrt{1+2h}+\sqrt{1+3h}}}{\dfrac{0-3}{\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{1+3h}}+\dfrac{2-3}{\sqrt{1+2h}+\sqrt{1+3h}}}$$

Comment: @daw, Please find the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Similar to egreg's answer, considering
$$\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{4x+12}}{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{4x+12}}$$ extract $\sqrt x$ for each term (and divide both numerator and denominator by  $\sqrt x$); now substitute $t=\frac 1x$ in each term.

So, the expression becomes $$\frac{\sqrt{1+t}+\sqrt{1+2t}-2\sqrt{1+3t}}
       {\sqrt{1+2t}+1-2\sqrt{1+3t}}$$ with $t\to 0$.

Now, using Taylor or generalized binomial theorem $$\sqrt{1+at}=1+\frac{a t}{2}-\frac{a^2 t^2}{8}+O\left(t^3\right)$$ So, the numerator becomes $$\left(1+\frac{t}{2}-\frac{t^2}{8}+O\left(t^3\right)\right)+\left(1+\frac{2t}{2}-\frac{4 t^2}{8}+O\left(t^3\right)\right)-2\left(1+\frac{3 t}{2}-\frac{9 t^2}{8}+O\left(t^3\right)\right)$$ that is to say $$-\frac{3 t}{2}+\frac{13 t^2}{8}+O\left(t^3\right)$$

For the denominator $$\left(1+\frac{2t}{2}-\frac{4 t^2}{8}+O\left(t^3\right)\right)+1-2\left(1+\frac{3 t}{2}-\frac{9 t^2}{8}+O\left(t^3\right)\right)=-2 t+\frac{7 t^2}{4}+O\left(t^3\right)$$ So,$$\frac{\sqrt{1+t}+\sqrt{1+2t}-2\sqrt{1+3t}}
       {\sqrt{1+2t}+1-2\sqrt{1+3t}}=\frac{-\frac{3 t}{2}+\frac{13 t^2}{8}+O\left(t^3\right) }{-2 t+\frac{7 t^2}{4}+O\left(t^3\right) }=\frac{-\frac{3 }{2}+\frac{13 t}{8}+O\left(t^2\right) }{-2 +\frac{7 t}{4}+O\left(t^2\right) }$$ Performing the long division, you will then get $$\frac{\sqrt{1+t}+\sqrt{1+2t}-2\sqrt{1+3t}}
       {\sqrt{1+2t}+1-2\sqrt{1+3t}}=\frac{3}{4}-\frac{5 t}{32}+O\left(t^2\right)$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{4x+12}}{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{4x+12}}=\frac{3}{4}-\frac{5 }{32x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

which shows the limit and also how it is approached.

Using $x=100$, the exact value is $\approx 0.748456$ while the above approximation gives $\frac{479}{640}\approx 0.748438$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\sqrt{4x + 12} = 2\sqrt{x + 3}$.  This unlocks all of the "secrets."

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Divide the numerator and denominator by $\sqrt x$. And use the fact that $x \to \infty$ implies $\frac{1}{ x} \to 0$.